# Can I read sharedpreference from Javascript in android?

Tags: javascript, android, security, sharedpreferences

In my Android application, if I download some `JavaScript` from a web URI, can that JavaScript read my native files like shared preferences or other files which I stored in my application's location?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, no. If it is running in a WebView and you have hooks to native methods in that (via `addJavascriptInterface()`), and the JS code you download knows (or guesses) what they are, it might be able to call them. Which could technically result in it reading files.

Comment: yea that is what i was thinking too. Unless the JS knows abt my addJavascriptInterface() object, they can't do it.

Comment: Of course, Android code an be reversed fairly easily, so it is not that hard to find out. If you are using JS interfaces, make sure they only do the bare minimum, check parameters, etc. Basically tread all input as potentially malicious.